# Kotlin type parameter subclass of

Tags: generics, kotlin

When I have this class:

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass<T> {
   abstract fun convert() : T
}
```

Can I somehow specify that `T` should be a subclass of `MyAbstractClass`?

**Edit**: `abstract class MyAbstractClass<T : MyAbstractClass>` does not work, because the `MyAbstractClass` in `<T : MyAbstractClass>` would require the type parameter again.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this one:

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass<T : MyAbstractClass<T>> {
    abstract fun convert(): T
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with following approach:

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass<out T : MyAbstractClass<T>> {
    abstract fun convert() : T
}

class ConcreteClass<T>(val str : String) : MyAbstractClass<ConcreteClass<T>>(){
    override fun convert(): ConcreteClass<T> = this
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val instance: MyAbstractClass<ConcreteClass<String>> = ConcreteClass("str")
    val converted: ConcreteClass<String> = instance.convert()
}
```

Comment: There are often reasons for going this route, see https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-enum/index.html for example. It's common enough to have a name: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov thanks for clarification, I have edited my answer accordingly.