# Classes common behavior + immutability in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics, design-patterns, immutability, data-class

Is there a way to achieve the following but in a more immutable way?

```kotlin
abstract class Abstract {
    abstract val general1: String
    abstract var counter: Int // Don't want to use var here

    fun sumCounter(value: Int) {
        counter += value
    }
}

data class A (
    val a1: String,

    override val general1: String,
    override var counter: Int = 0,
): Abstract()

data class B (
    val b1: String,
    val b2: String,

    override val general1: String,
    override var counter: Int = 1,
): Abstract()

fun <T : Abstract> doSomething(obj: T) {
    //...
    obj.sumCounter(10) // I want: val newObj = obj.sumCounter(10)


    println(obj) // A(a1=a1, general1=general1, counter=10)
                 // B(b1=b1, b2=b2, general1=general1, counter=11)
    //...
}

fun myMain() {
    val a = A("a1", "general1")
    doSomething(a)

    val b = B("b1", "b2", "general1")
    doSomething(b)
}
```

It could be some Kotlin trick, functional approach, or design pattern to avoid creating the same methods in `A` and `B`. But I don't want to use reflections or convert to json and back.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It should be possible using the technique described here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53765273/31506

Comment: @JoãoDias I'm trying to keep the behavior of `myMain` and `doSomething` without replicating code between `A`, `B`, and others, plus not using `var`s.

Comment: Your current code is probably more readable and usable than any approach to make it immutable, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

This is, unfortunately, the closest I got:

```
interface Abstract<out T: Abstract<T>> {
    val general1: String
    val counter: Int // Don't want to use var here
    fun copy(newCounter: Int): T

    fun sumCounter(value: Int): T = copy(newCounter = counter + value)
}

data class A (
    val a1: String,

    override val general1: String,
    override val counter: Int = 0,
): Abstract<A> {
    override fun copy(newCounter: Int): A = copy(counter = newCounter)
}

data class B (
    val b1: String,
    val b2: String,

    override val general1: String,
    override val counter: Int = 1,
): Abstract<B> {
    override fun copy(newCounter: Int): B = copy(counter = newCounter)
}

fun <T : Abstract<T>> doSomething(obj: T) {
    //...
    val newObj = obj.sumCounter(10)


    println(newObj) // A(a1=a1, general1=general1, counter=10)
    // B(b1=b1, b2=b2, general1=general1, counter=11)
    //...
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val a = A("a1", "general1")
    doSomething(a)

    val b = B("b1", "b2", "general1")
    doSomething(b)
}
```

You still need to duplicate the `copy()` method into each sub-class.